# How to update Fact when using static ISession Rules at runtime NRules

Tags: c#, nrules

Using NRules, I want to be able to create a session, insert facts, have it fire and complete, and while the session is still alive in memory (static variable) I want to call an update on the fact.

```
private static ISession session;  //this is instantiated when bulding the rules dinamically
public void RulesTest(RulesTest command)
    {
        //entities holds ALL facts ever inserted in session
        var entities = _session.Query<Entity>();
        _session.Insert(command.Fact);

        Rule rule = GetRule();
        _session.Insert(rule.Condition);
        _session.Insert(rule.Action);

        _session.Fire();
    }
```

This fires the rule and does everything properly.  What I want now to happen is to add the capibility of being able to update the SAME FACT that was fired once, but now with a new value...meaning, I want to update the fact, and have it run through the conditions again.

Doing `_session.Update(command.Fact)` after updating my fact gives me an error message: "Fact for update does not exist", even though I can see ALL facts still in session.

Any idea is welcome.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it if anyone else runs into this problem.  Preserving ISession (in the manner described above), use `_session.Query<Facts>()` in order to inspect what you already have.  Manipulate your code to make an update on this object.  After that call

```
_session.TryUpdate(Fact);
_session.Fire();
```

And it works :)